# Refresh a uma datatable

Tags: java, aplicação-web

É assim eu estou a fazer um pequeno site em java só que quando adiciono um produto e clico para listar a datatable não actualiza, não sei como e que tenho que fazer para que cada vez que a pagina for exibida actualizar o Array.

Outra coisa que me acontece e que quando adiciono um produto o campos nao ficam limpos.

Imagens (1 adicionei depois foi listar e como vêem não aparece a cenoura)

Inserir

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Listar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O que está usando? Só JSP? Spring?

Comment: estou a usar Spring com primefaces

Answer (score 0):

Já resolvi eu metia todas a class no spring ou seja assim

```
<bean id="Verificarsessao" class="service.Verificarsessao"></bean>
```

O que fazia com que pré carrega-se tudo nao sei se tou certo ou não mas resolveu o problema